# Jackson serialization ignore field annoted with non jackson annotation

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

is there a way to tell to Jackson to ignore fields during serialization which are annoted with non jackson annotation ?

for example :

```
@SomeAnnotation
private String foo;
```

I know there is jackson annotation to do that, but my fields are already annotated with my persistence annotation, so I'd like to avoid duplication since I already have field with annotation I'd like to ignore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would encourage you to just use `@JsonIgnore` because otherwise you're hiding something that's going on for those particular methods and dual-purposing annotations.

However... you can accomplish this by extending `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and overriding `_isIgnorable(Annotated)` like this:

```
publi class MyAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    protected boolean _isIgnorable(Annotated a) {
        boolean isIgnorable = super._isIgnorable(a);
        if (!isIgnorable) {
            SomeAnnotation ann = a.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
            isIgnorable = ann != null;
        }
        return isIgnorable;
    }
}
```

Then set the annotation introspector on your object mapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new MyAnnotationIntrospector());
```